# Writing to an array with MPI RMA

Tags: arrays, fortran, mpi

I want to write with accumulates (MPI RMA) to an array, which is accessible via a window. For easy checking I wrote to every cell its array-index. The Problem is, that the beginning seems to be always right but in the end there are sometimes wrong values: instead of its position-value the last entries are set to the final index.

My code:

```
PROGRAM main         
     USE mpi
     IMPLICIT NONE

     REAL*8, PARAMETER                         :: prec = 1d-13
     REAL(kind(prec)),ALLOCATABLE,DIMENSION(:) :: speicher1D
     INTEGER                                   :: stelle, ierror
     INTEGER                                   :: ix,iy,iz,nz,i
     !--------------------------------------------------------------
     !---------------MPI-Variablen----------------------------------
     !--------------------------------------------------------------
     INTEGER                        :: myRank               = 0
     INTEGER                        :: numProcs             = 1
     INTEGER, PARAMETER             :: masterProc           = 0

     INTEGER                        :: s3Win1D,s3Win3D
     INTEGER                        :: startIndex, endIndex
     INTEGER(KIND=MPI_ADDRESS_KIND) :: sizeOfSchritt3D1
     INTEGER(KIND=MPI_ADDRESS_KIND) :: s3TargetDisp
     INTEGER                        :: prec_mpi, sizeOfprec_mpi
     !--------------------------------------------------------------
     !--------------MAIN-PROGRAM------------------------------------
     !--------------------------------------------------------------        


     !----MPI-Initialisierung----
     CALL MPI_INIT(ierror)
     CALL MPI_COMM_RANK(MPI_COMM_WORLD, myRank,ierror)
     CALL MPI_COMM_SIZE(MPI_COMM_WORLD,numProcs, ierror)

     !Create new MPI-datatype
     CALL MPI_TYPE_CREATE_F90_REAL(KIND(prec), MPI_UNDEFINED, prec_mpi,ierror)         
     CALL MPI_TYPE_SIZE(prec_mpi, sizeOfprec_mpi,ierror)

     nz                     = 3
     sizeOfSchritt3D1       = sizeOfprec_mpi*(nz*2+1)**3

     ALLOCATE(speicher1D((nz*2+1)**3))
     !------------MPI-RMA-Initialisierung--------------------------
     CALL MPI_WIN_CREATE(speicher1D, sizeOfSchritt3D1, sizeOfprec_mpi,MPI_INFO_NULL,MPI_COMM_WORLD,s3Win1D, ierror)
     !Determine each proc's area
     startIndex  = (nz*2+1)/numProcs*myRank-nz
     endIndex    = (nz*2+1)/numProcs*(myRank+1)-nz-1
     IF(myRank+1 .EQ. numProcs) THEN
        endIndex = nz
     END IF

     speicher1D          = 0.0d0  
     CALL MPI_BARRIER(MPI_COMM_WORLD,ierror)
     CALL MPI_WIN_FENCE(0,s3Win1D, ierror)
     DO iz=startIndex, endIndex
       DO iy=-nz,nz
         DO ix=-nz,nz
           stelle = 1 + (iz+nz)*(2*nz+1)**2 + (iy+nz)*2*nz+1)+ (ix+nz)
           s3targetDisp = stelle-1
           !WRITE(*,*) "Rank", myRank,"s3targetDisp: ",s3targetDisp, "index: ",stelle
           !1D
           CALL MPI_ACCUMULATE(REAL(stelle,kind(prec)), 1, prec_mpi, masterProc, s3targetDisp,1,prec_mpi, MPI_SUM,s3Win1D, ierror)
         END DO 
       END DO
     END DO     
     CALL MPI_WIN_FENCE(0,s3Win1D, ierror)
     CALL MPI_BARRIER(MPI_COMM_WORLD, ierror)
     DO i = 1,(nz*2+1)**3
       IF(myRank .EQ. masterProc) THEN
         WRITE(*,*) "Index: ",i,", entry: ",speicher1D(i)
       END IF
     END DO
     DEALLOCATE(speicher1D)

     CALL MPI_WIN_FREE(s3Win1D, ierror)
     CALL MPI_FINALIZE(ierror)
  END PROGRAM main
```

I defined a new MPI-datatype prec_mpi and used three nested loops, because I need this schema for another (bigger) program. Using an integer to write to this double precision array is also intentional.

One wrong output I got ended for example as follows:

```
[...]
 Index:          250 , entry:    250.000000000000     
 Index:          251 , entry:    251.000000000000     
 Index:          252 , entry:    252.000000000000     
 Index:          253 , entry:    253.000000000000     
 Index:          254 , entry:    254.000000000000     
 Index:          255 , entry:    255.000000000000     
 Index:          256 , entry:    256.000000000000     
 Index:          257 , entry:    257.000000000000     
 Index:          258 , entry:    258.000000000000     
 Index:          259 , entry:    259.000000000000     
 Index:          260 , entry:    260.000000000000     
 Index:          261 , entry:    261.000000000000     
 Index:          262 , entry:    262.000000000000     
 Index:          263 , entry:    263.000000000000     
 Index:          264 , entry:    264.000000000000     
 Index:          265 , entry:    265.000000000000     
 Index:          266 , entry:    266.000000000000     
 Index:          267 , entry:    267.000000000000     
 Index:          268 , entry:    268.000000000000     
 Index:          269 , entry:    269.000000000000     
 Index:          270 , entry:    270.000000000000     
 Index:          271 , entry:    271.000000000000     
 Index:          272 , entry:    272.000000000000     
 Index:          273 , entry:    273.000000000000     
 Index:          274 , entry:    274.000000000000     
 Index:          275 , entry:    275.000000000000     
 Index:          276 , entry:    302.000000000000     
 Index:          277 , entry:    303.000000000000     
 Index:          278 , entry:    304.000000000000     
 Index:          279 , entry:    305.000000000000     
 Index:          280 , entry:    306.000000000000     
 Index:          281 , entry:    308.000000000000     
 Index:          282 , entry:    310.000000000000     
 Index:          283 , entry:    313.000000000000     
 Index:          284 , entry:    316.000000000000     
 Index:          285 , entry:    319.000000000000     
 Index:          286 , entry:    322.000000000000     
 Index:          287 , entry:    325.000000000000     
 Index:          288 , entry:    329.000000000000     
 Index:          289 , entry:    332.000000000000     
 Index:          290 , entry:    335.000000000000     
 Index:          291 , entry:    338.000000000000     
 Index:          292 , entry:    341.000000000000     
 Index:          293 , entry:    342.000000000000     
 Index:          294 , entry:    343.000000000000     
 Index:          295 , entry:    343.000000000000     
 Index:          296 , entry:    343.000000000000     
 Index:          297 , entry:    343.000000000000     
 Index:          298 , entry:    343.000000000000     
 Index:          299 , entry:    343.000000000000     
 Index:          300 , entry:    343.000000000000     
 [...]   
 Index:          341 , entry:    343.000000000000     
 Index:          342 , entry:    343.000000000000     
 Index:          343 , entry:    343.000000000000
```

Why is there such a jump in the entries (in this case after index 275)? The values for stelle and s3TargetDisp seem to me to be fine when I check them with the `write` inside the nested loops. Maybe it's some problem with synchronisation...but in the nested loop are just accumulates (no mixed RMA/local) and there is a closing fence.

Comment: sorry for that, I fixed it

Comment: This is not a correct MPI program. The RMA communication calls are *non-blocking* and must be treated as such: _"The local communication buffer of an RMA call should not be updated, and the local communication buffer of a get call should not be accessed after the RMA call until the operation completes at the origin."_ (MPI 3.1, Section 11.3) You are making multiple calls to `MPI_ACCUMULATE` before the synchronisation operation using *most likely* the same origin buffer - a temporary variable, in which the compiler stores the result of the conversion to real.

Comment: `real*8` is not valid Fortran and was never part of any ISO Fortran standard.

Comment: @jlokimlin Thanks for the hint, I'll consider this.

Comment: @HristoIliev Your're right, thank you. I add a `MPI_WIN_FENCE` at the end of the inner loop. Is there a better possibility to assure that I can reuse the buffer other than calling `MPI_WIN_Fence`? Now there are many syncs and because of my primitive load distribution I also need to add additional syncs outside the loop to match the last proc's syncs...

Comment: You cannot use MPI RMA as if you are simply accessing a shared memory region. Think of aggregating the access operations. For example, create a local array of size `(2*nz+1) x (2*nz+1) x (endIndex-startIndex+1)` and use it as the origin of a single `MPI_ACCUMULATE` operation.